# Laravel 5: jenssegers/laravel-date doesn't show correct translation. How do I use Laravel Date correctly?

Tags: php, html, datetime, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a simple L5 application, where I have to output some dates in a different language and therefore I am using [jenssegers/laravel-date package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date)

Yet, if I try to use jenssegers new package on my data stored in my database, I don't get the translation, see here:

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

use Jenssegers\Date\Date;
// This returns 'vor 0 Sekunden' in German, which I do want.
echo Date::now()->diffForHumans();

echo '<br/>';

// This returns '1 day ago'. It is in English, but I need it in German.
echo $orders->find(1)->created_at->diffForHumans();

@endsection
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this to happen is that `$orders->find(1)->created_at` returns a `Carbon` instance, not a `Date` one.

One approach to leverage `Date` is by doing it:

```
echo Date::instance($orders->find(1)->created_at)->diffForHumans();
```

You can use an [acessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to always return a Date object, like so:

**at your Order model:**

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Date::instance($value);
}
```

Comment: Yes I know. I did this, which is the reason the "echo Date::now()->diffForHumans();" returns the correct translated german string. Yet the other one does not.